# showing that $E[(\hat\theta -\theta)^2] \lt Var(\bar X)=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\theta, 1),\theta_0 \lt\theta$ ,  Find the MLE of $\theta$ and show that it is better than the sample mean $\bar X$ in the sense of having smaller mean squared error.

Trial: Here MLE of $\theta$ is $$\hat\theta =
\begin{cases}
\theta_0, &\bar X \lt \theta_0\\
\bar X, &\theta_0 \le \bar X  \\
\end{cases}$$

I can't show that $E[(\hat\theta -\theta)^2] \lt Var(\bar X)=\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: The mean squared error is the same as the sample variance only if the estimator is unbiased.  In this case, suppose $\theta=\theta_0$, and ask what the expected value of the MLE is.  The MLE has probability $1/2$ of being equal to $\theta$ and probabiluty $1/2$ of being $>\theta$, so its expected value is $>\theta$, i.e. it is biased.  The MSE is the variance plus the square of the bias. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing $\bar{X}$ is inadmissible estimator of under Squared error loss function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213955/showing-barx-is-inadmissible-estimator-of-under-squared-error-loss-function)

Comment: @BruceTrumbo It's better to close the other copy, as this one has more content.